# How does "arch -arch" work to enable Rosetta and force binary architecture?

Tags: macos, mach-o, universal-binary, rosetta, lipo

When using [Rosetta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosetta_(software)) on macOS running on an ARM processor, the [`arch`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/arch/) command can be used to force a wrapped command to execute as a specific architecture. In other words, `arch -arch x86_64 mycommand` will try to launch `mycommand` as an x86/Intel program. If `mycommand` is ARM-only, it will fail; if `mycommand` is a [universal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_binary) binary, it will be run as x86.

But how does the `arch -arch ...` command actually work? Specifically, I have these questions:

- By what mechanism does `arch -arch $arch $program` select a `$arch` from a universal binary `$program` and run it?
- By what mechanism does `arch -arch  $arch $program` try to run a *non*-universal binary `$program` as the selected architecture `$arch`, causing a failure if the binary doesn't support it?
- Is it possible for another program to do what `arch` does here, without shelling out to `arch`? Even if it's possible-but-not-recommended/a private macOS API, I'm still interested in how it happens.

I'm asking this out of curiosity, not because I need to get around what `arch` does.

I've tried:

- Looking into the guts of `lipo` while making universal binaries. `lipo` seems to be concatenating binaries for different architectures together in a Mach-O "fat binary" container with some magic bits at the top to indicate what contents are where. This helps a little bit with the first question above, but doesn't help with the second or third.
- Looking into fat binary parsing tools like [mach_object](https://docs.rs/mach_object/latest/mach_object/). It seems theoretically possible for me to extract the appropriate sub-binary from a fat binary, dump it to a temp file, and execute it, but that seems like it would have all sorts of problems (CWD would be wrong, writing a file just to launch a program seems wasteful).

Comment: Check the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/system_cmds/system_cmds-671.10.3/arch.tproj/arch.c.auto.html) -- it uses posix_spawn() with a [special option in the attributes](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/posix_spawnattr_setbinpref_np.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/posix_spawnattr_setbinpref_np).

Comment: That is it, thank you! If you write that comment in an answer, I'll accept it.